# HttpWebResponse get stuck while running in a loop

Tags: c#, .net, webrequest, httpwebresponse, getresponse

I build this method (c#) in order to receive the HTTP response status code from an URL.
whene I run this method ones it's works fine, but when I run it in a loop, the third time its stuck. any clue??

```
 public static string isAlive(string url)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("start: Is Alive Test");
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            return Convert.ToString((int)response.StatusCode);
        }
        catch(WebException ex)
        {
            HttpWebResponse res  = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
            return Convert.ToString((int)res.StatusCode);
        }
    }
```

the loop

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            string a = isAlive("https://www.yahoo.com/");
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's stuck and not just waiting for a response? There's  good chance that the server is throttling the requests because it might detect suspicious activity (throwing so many requests to a server in such a short space of time can appear to be a DoS attack). Given you want to make numerous requests without blocking the UI thread you might want to consider going for `BeginX`/`EndX` calls instead.

Comment: Define 'stuck'. If your program is hanging after three attempts it could be that the yahoo server is rejecting your rapid succession of `https` requests. Another alternative is that your OS is preventing rapid connections to the same address (internal flood protection). edit - the answer is the other alternative, you have too many connections open at once.

Comment: You need to wrap .GetResponse() into `using` statement and make your isAlive method async for performance considerations. See my code sample below.

Comment: @James, I never said that wrapping `GetResponse` into `using` makes it async. Where did you get that from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not calling `Dispose` on the `HttpWebResponse` object, which means that the connection is still lying around. If you change your code to the following:

```
public static string isAlive(string url)
{
   Console.WriteLine("start: Is Alive Test");
   WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
   try
   {
       using(HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            return Convert.ToString((int)response.StatusCode);
        }

   }
   catch(WebException ex)
   {
       using(HttpWebResponse res  = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response)
       {
          return Convert.ToString((int)res.StatusCode);
       }
   }
}
```

the `using` statement will implicitly call Dispose for you, which will close the connection.

The reason your code is halting after the second iteration is because .Net has a built in maximum number of connections it will open to a website, which is by default 2. This is controlled by `System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` which you can increase should you need to.

Comment: I think you have to do the same for `ex.Response`.

Comment: Although I agree they should wrap this with `using`, I doubt it's the cause of the problem. The `response` object would get disposed once it goes out of scope of the `isAlive` call eventually (not immediately though). Nor should this affect subsequent calls.

Comment: @James that's assuming that you leave the app enough time for the garbage collector to clean up after every iteration.

Comment: The framework uses connection pooling to handle HTTP requests, so not immediately closing the connection is a plausible cause of this problem.

Comment: @StevenLiekens actually I stand corrected, the default max connection is 2 as per the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1tkaca2y(v=vs.110).aspx) - so this more than likely *is* the problem so +1.

Answer (score 1):

- You need to wrap `HttpWebResponse` var into `using` statement because it's disposable
- Before checking `ex.Response.StatusCode` make sure that ex.Status is a `ProtocolError`
- And also consider making your method asynchronous for performance considerations
- Since your method is returning a status code, there might be a better name for it than isAlive

Sample:

```
public static async Task<string> GetStatusCode(string url)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    try
    {
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            return response.StatusCode.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        return ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError ?
                ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode.ToString() : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with you not closing the HttpWebResponse.
Add a finally to that try catch which closes the response.
Also close the WebException response within the catch.

Answer (score 0):

Use "using" and it will work well.

```
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            return Convert.ToString((int)response.StatusCode);
        }
```